# mat-selection-list component is very slow in IE11 and working fine in other browsers

Tags: angular, performance, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

I am using mat-selection-list in my application and more than 100 options with checkboxes, it is working in chrome, firefox and edge but in IE11 it is very slow and hangs.

Here is the sample code:

```html
<mat-selection-list #options [(ngModel)]="selectOptions" [compareWith]="compareFunction" (selectionChange)="onOptionSel($event)">
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let cio of ciOptions" checkboxPosition="before" [value]="cio" aria-label="cio">
{{cio.label}}
```

Comment: You are missing sample code

Comment: With the information you provided it is hard to help you with your problem. Try to make it as easy as possible for others to reproduce / analyze your problem. Provide more context and more code and don't forget to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

after trying *cdkVirtualFor instead of *ngFor it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.